# Why is my IBOutlet being released under ARC?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting, iboutlet

**The Problem**

An IBOutlet is released before I have a chance to use it.

**What I Want**

I want to access a navigation controller from my app delegate so I can reload a table view.

**My Setup**

I have:

- A Main.xib that's set as my main interface in target settings
- An IBOutlet to the navigation controller as an ivar on my app delegate
- This IBOutlet hooked up to the correct navigation controller in Main.xib
- App Delegate is instantiated in the xib but not set as File's Owner

I'm using ARC, Xcode 4.3.2 and iOS5.1

**What I've Tried**

- Changing deployment target
- Putting a break point on dealloc for the navigation controller, app delegate - they're never called
- Reading everything I can find on ARC and IBOutlets - nothing seems to contradict what I'm doing
- Creating a fresh project with just a the minimum classes required - I see exactly the same  problem

**Code**

**KPAppDelegate.h**

```
@interface KPAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet  KPBrowseExpensesNavigationController *nc;
}

@property (strong) IBOutlet KPBrowseExpensesNavigationController *nc;
```

**KPAppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation KPAppDelegate

@synthesize nc;

-(void)setNc:(KPBrowseExpensesNavigationController *)nc_ {
    nc = nc_; // This gets called on view load and nc gets set.
}

...snip...

// This is called about 5 seconds after app startup
-(void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects {
        // By the time we get here, nc is nil.
        UITableViewController *tvc = [[nc viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        [[tvc tableView] reloadData];
}

@end
```

**UPDATE**

I *must* be doing something really silly here. Even an incredibly simple project still shows this problem. See link below.

[Download a simple test project that shows the problem.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/86403596/TestIBOutletDelloc1.zip)

Comment: Very VERY good example of a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Window nib, set the FilesOwner Class as UIApplication and then point it's delegate from Outlets to the AppDelegate object. This is what is wrong in your project example.

Comment: You, sir, are brilliant. This did occur to me, but since the delegate seemed to be getting executed, I thought this wouldn't be the issue. I wish I'd tried this 5 hours ago...! Thanks again.

Comment: no problem, it is easier to figure it out on a project than of some line of codes here. So you did very good by explaining with an example of a project:)

Answer (score 2):

is your outlet from the Interface Builder set as an `KPBrowseExpensesNavigationController` type?
If not it is not going to create the connection between your nib and ViewController.

You should set its Custom Class as KPBrowseExpensesNavigationController in the Identity Inspector

Comment: Still not working. The outlet/ivar is still nil. See my update above for an ultra simple project that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you declare it as a property & a non-property. I should do something like this:

```
@interface KPAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> 

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet KPBrowseExpensesNavigationController *nc;
```

And in your implementation:

```
@implementation KPAppDelegate

@synthesize nc = _nc; // So you don't accidentally use nc

...snip...

// This is called about 5 seconds after app startup
-(void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects {
        // By the time we get here, nc is nil.
        UITableViewController *tvc = [[**self.nc** viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        [[tvc tableView] reloadData];
}

@end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it's still nil. :( I clearly misunderstood @property so thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see where you alloc your nav controller. Just declaring the property won't assign any value to it, so it would be nil. In you `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the app delegate, set your alloc/init statement. Everything else looks fine.

```
KPBrowseExpensesNavigationController *nc = [[KPBrowseExpensesNavigationController alloc] init];
```

If you have a custom init, you can use that too, but just make sure to set it up before you try and use it.

Comment: The controller was initialized in the nib file. But thanks for the suggestion!